# Datatables Json Array as Datasource

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am not sure what I am doing wrong , i have a pretty simple JSON object :

```
[{"siteName":"Site 1","issueType":"Scada programming Defect","issueSeverity":"Critical","issueDate":"21/10/2021","issueSource":"Customer Feedback","problemSummary":"Test Probelm S1","reportedBy":"rehan.azher@gmail.com","assignedTo":"rehan.azher@gmail.com","sitePic":"Automation Team","picEmail":"Testing","customerName":"Test Customer","problemDetail":"Problem Detail2","status":"OPEN","tickettime":"2021-10-23T14:45:18.016Z","ticketid":"BBP-000001"}]
```

I have mapped to a simplest Datatable configuration:

```
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped  table-bordered" style="width:100%"></table>
```

And am trying to populate the table using Jquery Javascript as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log(dataArray);
        $('#data-table').DataTable({
            data: dataArray,
             responsive: true,
             columns: [
        { data: 'ticketid' },
        { data: 'siteName' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: 'issueType' }
    ],
             
             fnInitComplete : function() {
      $("#overlay").hide();
   }
           
        });
    });
```

it gives me error always :

> DataTables warning: table id=data-table - Requested unknown parameter 'ticketid' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Your code works for me with no errors, when I add `var dataArray = [ { "siteName": "Site 1", ..., "ticketid": "BBP-000001" } ];` to your script. That is missing from your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that , the problem was variable returned from backend ```dataArray``` was String , simply parsing it to JSON did the trick.

Comment: Great! - I am glad it is solved. You can answer your own question to help other visitors to this question in the future. (Or, in this case, there may already be a duplicate question you can link to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was variable `dataArray` was being returned as String , simply parsing to JSON did the trick.

Hope this can help others.